# @apply` cannot be used with `.bg-blue` because `.bg-blue` either cannot be found, or its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use @apply in my sass file, and getting the error in the title when I do npm run dev or npm run watch. I'm using Laravel, and using Laravel Mix. Here is my webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [ tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js') ],
    });
```

This exists in my app.css

```
...
.bg-blue {
  background-color: #47cdff;
}
```

My app.scss:

```
// Tailwind CSS
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

// Custom CSS
.section {
    @apply .px-4;
}

.button {
    @apply .bg-blue .text-white .no-underline .rounded-lg .text-sm .py-2 .px-5;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 #b0eaff;
}
```

Comment: This may help you.. https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/396

Comment: What version of tailwindcss are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson v1.0.3

Comment: Have you displayed your whole `app.scss` file there aren't any includes in your example? How are you adding `.bg-blue` to your css?

Comment: That's my whole app.scss. My button has the class `button` that you can see in my app.scss, which should also apply bg-blue from my app.css file

Answer (score 1):

Just override the default color pallete, you can do so using the theme.colors section of your tailwind.config.js file :

```
  theme: {
    colors: {
      white: '#FFFFFF',
      blue: '#007ace',

    }
  }
```

Then an easy trick never mix regular CSS and imports in the same file. Instead, create one main entry-point file for your imports, and keep all of your actual CSS in separate files.